# how can i compare two csv files?

Tags: file, comparison

train.csv:

> 01kcPWA9K2BOxQeS5Rju  1
>
> 04EjIdbPV5e1XroFOpiN  1
>
> 05EeG39MTRrI6VY21DPd  1
>
> 05rJTUWYAKNegBk2wE8X  1
>
> 0AnoOZDNbPXIr2MRBSCJ  1
>
> 0AwWs42SUQ19mI7eDcTC  1
>
> 0cH8YeO15ZywEhPrJvmj  1
>
> 0DNVFKwYlcjO7bTfJ5p1  1
>
> 0DqUX5rkg3IbMY6BLGCE  1
>
> 0eaNKwluUmkYdIvZ923c  1
>
> 0fHVZKeTE6iRb1PIQ4au  1
>
> 0G4hwobLuAzvl1PWYfmd  1

test.csv:

> 01IsoiSMh5gxyDYTl4CB
>
> 01SuzwMJEIXsK7A8dQbl
>
> 01azqd4InC7m9JpocGv5
>
> 01jsnpXSAlgw6aPeDxrU
>
> 01kcPWA9K2BOxQeS5Rju
>
> 02IOCvYEy8mjiuAQHax3
>
> 02JqQ7H3yEoD8viYWlmS
>
> 02K5GMYITj7bBoAisEmD
>
> 02MRILoE6rNhmt7FUi45
>
> 02mlBLHZTDFXGa7Nt6cr
>
> 02zcUmKV16Lya5xqnPGB
>
> 03nJaQV6K2ObICUmyWoR
>
> 04BfoQRA6XEshiNuI7pF
>
> 04EjIdbPV5e1XroFOpiN

these type of rows and i want each row compare with train.csv rows and find the match where it match save the id against that row and output should be like this:

output.csv:

> 01kcPWA9K2BOxQeS5Rju  2
>
> 04EjIdbPV5e1XroFOpiN  2
>
> 05EeG39MTRrI6VY21DPd  4
>
> 05rJTUWYAKNegBk2wE8X  1
>
> 0AnoOZDNbPXIr2MRBSCJ  1
>
> 0AwWs42SUQ19mI7eDcTC  5
>
> 0cH8YeO15ZywEhPrJvmj  5
>
> 0DNVFKwYlcjO7bTfJ5p1  1
>
> 0DqUX5rkg3IbMY6BLGCE  3
>
> 0eaNKwluUmkYdIvZ923c  1
>
> 0fHVZKeTE6iRb1PIQ4au  1
>
> 0G4hwobLuAzvl1PWYfmd  2

Kindly help me

Comment: What are the tools you have? Pandas, R? Excel?

Comment: canopy with python environment